# iAds are not displayed

Tags: iphone

I have implemented iAds as in [Ray's Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app). It was showing sample adds in the development build. I made a app store build, and upload it on app store.

Now apple approved it and I downloaded same build from the iTunes. When I am running app there are no adds shown. I checked the iTunes connect for iAds network settings. its showing it is live. does any one has any idea why this is happening??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is probably fine. The fill rate -- the percentage of requests for ads that are fulfilled -- is pretty low for iAd usually (last time I checked, the fill rate for my app was less than 20%) and it's not supported in every country. If you're in a country that has inventory, if you keep trying you'll eventually see an ad.